# How do I add timestamps to bot logs?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is there a way to add a timestamp to when my bot logs something to the console?
For example, when it leaves a server, it says:

> I have been removed from the guild: "Server"

And I want it to look something like [Day, Time]:

> [May 10, 2022, 15:35] I have been removed from the guild: "Server"

Comment: You can use `new Date()` to achieve that. Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date as a helpful reference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Date and normalize it with simple module `moment.js`.

Install it on terminal with `npm i moment`.

```js
const moment = require("moment")
moment.locale("en")

client.on("guildDelete", async guild => {
console.log(`[${moment(Date.now()).format("LLL")}] I have been removed from the guild: ${guild.name}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use [log-timestamp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-timestamp) npm package to do so!

steps:

1. type `npm i log-timestamp` in console.
2. paste it in your main index.js file!

```
require('log-timestamp')
```

all set! now you will get timestamp in every logging in console!

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `log` function (e.g. `client.log()`) instead of `console.log()`. This allows you to modify logs without changing global prototype (bad practice!)

[Example of my TS discord bot's custom logger](https://github.com/thetayloredman/Lexi/blob/af98ebb7834e8c28aab0ef0243265574797aab22/src/log.ts#L162-L164)

It is thrown around as `log` on every function. Note this code is a little advanced, so it may confuse newer readers.